# "Class not found" error even after dump-autoload?

Tags: php, laravel-4, composer-php

I keep getting the "Class not found" error with newly created models. I know the syntax is absolutely correct.  I went over it multiple times and I copied and pasted variables to avoid spelling errors.

I also ran

```
php artisan dump-autoload
```

mulitple times, but still no luck.  This happens in every file, and it only happens to the newly created models.

Comment: What are your model's names ? I saw one issue like this where the model had underscores "_" in its name and that was apparently the issue.

Comment: Paste your model, is it a namespaced model? does your composer.json file include the model directory in the autoload section?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `composer` instead.

```
php composer dump-autoload
```

If you are not generating the models don't forget to add the folder in the *composer.json* at *autoload* if it isn't.

Comment: @user1521753 You should also post the error and the code in your model.